# How to prevent autofocus on first input item when I click a link on popup in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, popup, autofocus, keypad

I have a textarea and a link in a jQuery Mobile popup.
When I click link, textarea gets focused automatically and keypad is showing. (on ios)
I wanted to redirect to another page by clicking the link, but before it redirects, keypad is showing which is not necessary as I don't want to change any text.

I checked jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 demo page but it has same issue:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/

But it seems 1.3.1 has no such issue.

Please help me!!!

Comment: Did you take a loot at the [blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) function ?
It removes focus from the element.

Comment: I used blur() function but as ios tried to show & hide keypad so page is sliding up and down in a few milliseconds. So I just wanted to prevent to get focused on the input.

Answer (score 1):

try add this before the first input elements `<button style="position:fixed; top:10px; left:10px; opacity:0"></button>`